# Eclipse 'Open PHP Type' dialog box

Tags: php, eclipse, types

In Eclipse, what is the purpose of the

> *Open PHP Type* Dialog box (Ctrl+Shift+T)

I have huge PHP5 project and nothing happens what ever I type in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that you have to define the type of each of your objets in your class in order to use this function later to browse your code.

To define a type do as follow :

```
/* @var $var_name var_type */
```

here is a concrete exemple

```
/* @var $pagamenti Zend_Db_Table_Rowset */
```

And don't forget a space after var_type.

Thanks @atlanto